# EMC Documentum: Get previous version of IDfSysObject

Tags: java, documentum, dfc

If we use `IDfId checkin(boolean keepLock,
              String versionLabels)
              throws DfException` method, we get new version of `IDfSysObject`. How can I remove the latest version and get back to the previous version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To revert to a previous major version You need to do the following:

1. get any previous major version of object You need to make current as IDfPersistentObject.
2. Add "CURRENT" to [0] index in R_VERSION_LABEL attribute
3. save modified IDfPersistentObject
4. get all IDfPersistentObject  with R_VERSION_LABEL > than your new current version
5. remove "CURRENT" from [0] index in R_VERSION_LABEL if it exists.
6. save IDfPersistentObject
7. call IDfPersistentObject.destroy(). It will not fail.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to keep the latest then you can check out the latest version, read the contents of the previous version in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` using the `getContent()` method and set that content to the latest version, using `setContent()`.

Or if you do not wish to keep the latest version you user the `IDfPersistentObject.destroy()` method for the object to delete the only latest version so the previous version will become current.

Comment: `destroy()` doestn't work. Exception is being thrown. There are some dependencies which don't allow to destroy latest version. I still can't find these dependencies. 

And I don't need the current latest version, yeah. So destroying is ok.